# css input:read-only applying background to ordinary buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I have an application with many read-only inputs.  To save coding I used the css pseudo class input and my css reads

```
input:-moz-read-only{
 background:#d8ebeb;
}

input:read-only{
  background:#d8ebeb;
}
```

While this works fine for inputs with readonly, unfortunately it is also coloring some ordinary buttons.

[image]

The code for the "listing of event types" button is:

```
<input type  = "button"
       id      = "#basetab#" 
       class   = "onoffbutdarkblue onoffextension"
       value   = "listing of #title#"                                
       onclick = "xrefbuttonsubmit('xrep.cfm','xrefform')">
```

Obviously I have not indicated "readonly" for this button, but apparently Firefox is applying the background anyway.  This is true for every button in the system where the background is not explicitly specified.

What I want is the default white background on all the buttons, unless I specify otherwise. I am in linux/firefox/coldfusion.

Can anyone offer me a simple fix that will leave my readonlys green and my other buttons white?  Is there a button pseudo class? Some other approach?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only That selector styles everything that can not be edited by the user. Why not add a class to the buttons you want to style differently?

Comment: The button does not have exactly the same background color as the readonly ones you have indicated, are you sure something else isn't setting the color? Perhaps put up a working snippet which shows the problem, and look in your browser inspect tools to see exactly who/what is setting that element's background.

Comment: @JHeth -- I'd certainly add a class to the differently styled buttons if I knew what they were.  The readonly is determined by a table, so there is no way for me to know in advance which ones will be readonly.

Comment: @AHaworth a good suggestion and I'll check it out.

Comment: @AHaworth I just checked it out.  the -moz-read-only is definitely creating the background.   Following this clue, I tried a number of things.  Getting rid of -moz-read-only and using only input:readonly solved the problem.  I suspect the -moz version is out of date.

Comment: Glad it worked, will investigate the -moz version some more just in case see it in the future.